# Lightning tab with LWC name stuck in "Loading"

Tags: lightning-web-components, workspaceapi, lightning-tab

I created a lightning tab with a LWC and the name of the tab is stuck in "Loading.." in apps such as console, when I search about that, I saw that the most used way to correct this is put the LWC inside a aura component. It this still true? Because I saw that it's possible to import "uiWorkspaceApi".

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure as you have not posted the code here. Please post sample code to understand your question better.
Here is a sample to create a tab in LWC. I don't see any issue loading name

**HTML**

```
<template>
    <lightning-card>
        <h1 class="slds-text-align_center slds-text-heading_large">
            LWC Custom Tab Example
        </h1>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

***META FILE***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>56.0</apiVersion>
    <description>Lightning Web Component Tab Example</description>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__Tab</target>
    </targets>
    <masterLabel>Lightning Web Component Tab Example</masterLabel>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

***JS***

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class SampleTab extends LightningElement {}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]